# Skip particular get value from url in php

Tags: php

```
$url="http://services.php?service_cat=14;&mess_pop=Service_cart";
```

and

```
$url="http://index.php?mess_pop=Thank_you";
```

from these urls, I want new url without `$_GET['mess_pop']`.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use [parse_url](https://www.php.net/parse_url) to get the different parts of the URL
2. Turn the "query" part of the URL into an array with [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).
3. Unset the value in the array that you don't want.
4. Turn the array back into a query string value with [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)
5. Rebuild the parts of the URL that you got back from step 1

```php
$url = parse_url($url);
parse_str($url['query'], $qs);
unset($qs['mess_pop']);
$url['query'] = http_build_query($qs);
$url = $url['scheme'] . '://' . $url['host'] . $url['path'] . '?' . $url['query'];
```

Comment: thank you , a small issue in it, finally should be $url = $url['host'] . $url['path'] . '?' . $url['query'];                                instead of                                                       $url = $url['scheme'] . '://' . $url['host'] . $url['path'] . '?' . $url['query'];

Comment: @prakash The $url['scheme'] bit is to put in if it is http or https. The final code should really check each of the entries in the parsed url to make sure they exist.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over all `$_GET` parameters, add them to a new array, and skip the message.

```
$new_get = array();

foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
{
   if($key != 'mess_pop')
   {
       $new_get[$key] => $value;
   }
}
```

To generate a new url:

```
$url_query = "?";
foreach($new_get as $key => $value)
{
    $url_query .= urlencode($key) .'='. urlencode($value) .'&';
}

// To remove last '&'
$url_query = trim($url_query, '&');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
$out = array();
parse_str($url, $out);
unset($out['mess_pop']);
$newURL = 'http://index.php?' . http_build_query($out);
```

Comment: Cool, did not know about `http_build_query` yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$parse_url=parse_url($url);
parse_str($parse_url['query'],$parse_str);
unset($parse_str['mess_pop']);
$new_url=http_build_query($parse_str);
```